# Cannot create two REST methods with different arguments

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, controller

I m trying to create two methods with the same name but with different parameters but I m getting an error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found.

Here are the two methods :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/hikes",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public void create(@RequestBody HikeDto hikedto) {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/hikes",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public void create(@RequestBody HikeDto hikedto, ArrayList<HikeDto> hikes) {...}
```

Is what I want to do possible?

thank you.